# Universal links with IP Address

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-links

I have implement Universal Links in my project, but the testing server do not have domain name.

By following the steps from official documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

I fill in "applinks:{ip address}" into Associated Domains, but it not work.

Is there must use domain name for Universal Links feature?

Comment: So do you make it work by replacing the ip address with a domain name?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Universal Links are resolved during domain name resolution so they will not support bare IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to fill in a domain name here - this should be the domain or subdomain you're wanting to use for Universal Links. You can also verify your domain with this tool to make sure it's serving https etc, and see your app's bundle identifier there:
https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/

I hope this helps!